# Full text elasticsearch filltering nested objects and hits order hits by score of the field

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have 2 documents, ShopDocument and ProductDocument. What i need is to filter out all shops that have field `hidden` and `removed` equals to `true`, from shops that left filter out products that have `removed` and `hidden` fields equal to `true`, then from whats left, i want to filter out shops and products that doesnt match certain string (the matching needs to be in certain fields) and sort the results according to score that i will give to each field (like in lucene). This is my documents:

```
@Document(indexName = Indices.SHOP_INDEX)
@Setting(settingPath = Constants.esSettingsPath)
@Data
public class ShopDocument {

@Id
@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
private Long id;

@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
private Long companyId;

@Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
private Boolean companyHidden;

@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
private String slug;

@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
private String postalCode;

@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
private String addressLine;

@Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
private boolean hidden;

@Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
private boolean removed;

@Field(type = FieldType.Text)
private String name;

@Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
private List<ProductDocument> products = new ArrayList<>();

@Field(type = FieldType.Double)
private Double latitude;

@Field(type = FieldType.Double)
private Double longitude;

@Field(type = FieldType.Integer)
private Integer maxDeliveryDistance;
}



@Document(indexName = Indices.Product_INDEX)
@Setting(settingPath = Constants.esSettingsPath)
@Data
public class ProductDocument {

@Id
@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
private String id;

@Field(type = FieldType.Text)
private String name;

@Field(type = FieldType.Text)
private String description;

@Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
private boolean hidden;

@Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
private boolean removed;

@Field(type = FieldType.Long)
private Long oldPrice;

@Field(type = FieldType.Long)
private Long price;
```

**I had tried the following:**

```
    BoolQueryBuilder builder = boolQuery();

    builder.must(termQuery("hidden", false))
            .must(termQuery("removed", false))
            .must(nestedQuery("products", termQuery("products.hidden", false), ScoreMode.None))
            .must(nestedQuery("products", termQuery("products.removed", false), ScoreMode.None));

            SearchHits<ShopDocument> searchHits = operations.search(qb.build(), ShopDocument.class, IndexCoordinates.of(Indices.SHOP_INDEX));
```

This query should return all shops with `hidden` and `removed` equals to `false` and all products in shops that have `hidden` and `removed` equals to `false` but it only filters out shops and leaves the products as is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the method `innerHits` of class `NestedQueryBuilder`.
This method retrieves just the nested objects that match.
Therefore your code becomes:

```java
BoolQueryBuilder builder = boolQuery();
builder.must(termQuery("hidden", false))
       .must(termQuery("removed", false))
       .must(nestedQuery("products", termQuery("products.hidden", false), ScoreMode.None).innerHits(new InnerHitBuilder()));
       .must(nestedQuery("products", termQuery("products.removed", false), ScoreMode.None).innerHits(new InnerHitBuilder()));

SearchHits<ShopDocument> searchHits = operations.search(qb.build(), ShopDocument.class, IndexCoordinates.of(Indices.SHOP_INDEX));
```